# PL/SQL Records. Can i put in records few values?

Tags: oracle, plsql, record

I'm working in Apex Oracle PL/SQL and trying to understand how records work.
There is piece of code. I can't understand why i'm getting exception "no data found".
And can i put few rows in records?

```
create table testProducts 
    (
        prod_id number not null,
         group_id number (5) not null,
        prod_name varchar2(50) not null,
        constraint fk_group_id foreign key (group_id)
        references testGroups(group_id)
    )



declare
    type mr is record (
        prod_Id testProducts.prod_Id%type
    );
    obj_mr mr;

    maxd number;

egin
    select max(prod_Id) into maxd from testProducts;
    for i in 10..maxd loop
        select testProducts.prod_id into obj_mr from testProducts where 
        testProducts.prod_Id = i;
        dbms_output.put_line(obj_mr.prod_id);
       
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your for-loop starts in 10 and not in 1?

Comment: put some data in table `testProducts `or else handle the exception (should be handled )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your immediate issues, you are getting a **no data found** error because you are starting looping at `prod_id` 10 and going up sequentially to the maximum `prod_id` that exists in the table. If you have any gaps in your IDs then you will get the error. You can resolve it with some error handling like this:

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE mr IS RECORD
    (
        prod_Id      testProducts.prod_Id%TYPE,
        GROUP_ID     testProducts.GROUP_ID%TYPE,
        prod_name    testProducts.prod_name%TYPE
    );
    
    obj_mr   mr;

    maxd     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX (prod_Id) INTO maxd FROM testProducts;

    FOR i IN 10 .. NVL (maxd, 1)
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            SELECT prod_id, GROUP_ID, prod_name
              INTO obj_mr
              FROM testProducts
             WHERE prod_Id = i;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (obj_mr.prod_id || '|' || obj_mr.GROUP_ID || '|' || obj_mr.prod_name);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
            THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('prod_id does not exist: ' || i);
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

To answer your question about multiple rows, no a **RECORD** type can not have multiple rows, but a **TABLE** type can. If you define a **TABLE** type of your **RECORD** type, you can then select multiple rows in to that **TABLE** type. See the code below for an example of how to do that.

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE mr IS RECORD
    (
        prod_Id      testProducts.prod_Id%TYPE,
        GROUP_ID     testProducts.GROUP_ID%TYPE,
        prod_name    testProducts.prod_name%TYPE
    );

    TYPE mr_t IS TABLE OF mr;

    obj_mr_t   mr_t;
BEGIN
      SELECT prod_id, GROUP_ID, prod_name
        BULK COLLECT INTO obj_mr_t
        FROM testProducts
    ORDER BY prod_id;

    FOR i IN 1 .. obj_mr_t.COUNT
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            obj_mr_t (i).prod_id || '|' || obj_mr_t (i).GROUP_ID || '|' || obj_mr_t (i).prod_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```